# How to fix 'Cannot read property 'value' of null' with an input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, input

I want to show the value of an  in my console.
But when I try to console.log the value, it says that value of 'null' can't be read

I have tried making this in my HTML file with  but it doesn't work too

Here is my code :

```js
var grayscale = document.getElementById('grayscale');
console.log(grayscale.value)

grayscale.onchange = function(){
    console.log(grayscale.value)
}
```

```html
<input type='range' id='grayscale' min='0' max='100'>
```

And it shows

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at main.js:3
```

Comment: When does your JavaScript run, exactly? Before or after the main HTML document is constructed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.onload` and call a function, which performs all the tasks you want. It will wait till window loads and then your function will be executed. Right now it is getting executed before the html is getting rendered, means it is accessing the value of the slider before even it is loaded. So you get the error.

```js
window.onload=function(){var grayscale = document.getElementById('grayscale');
console.log(grayscale.value)

grayscale.onchange = function(){
    console.log(grayscale.value)
}
}
```

```html
<input type='range' id='grayscale' min='0' max='100'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript is running before the DOM is ready.  Try wrapping it in an event listener like:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var grayscale = document.getElementById('grayscale');
  console.log(grayscale.value)

  grayscale.onchange = function(){
    console.log(grayscale.value)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is your answer, Or place at the bottom of your documents, before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
const grayscale = document.getElementById('grayscale');

grayscale.addEventListener('change', ({target}) => console.log(target.value));
```

ps: forgot to mention, when launch script, set attribute defer, like below:

```
<script defer src="./index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the Javascript after the element. If grayscale is null, it is not part of the DOM yet. Put the Javascript file or snippet in the body section at the very end after your element.

```
<html>
  ....
  <body>
     ....
     <script type="text/javascript" src="theJs.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or you can use embedded javascript:

```
<input type='range' id='grayscale' min='0' max='100'>
<script>
var grayscale = document.getElementById('grayscale');
console.log(grayscale.value)

grayscale.onchange = function(){
    console.log(grayscale.value)
}
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing statements won't usually work with null, especially with less lenient JavaScript Frameworks probably.
You just have to add a negator (!) in front instead to make it work .

let variable = null

```
  if(!variable) {
console.log("computing")
  }
```

Either that or you might be making the common mistake of going one step deeper than you should be.